# Nested binding and piped conversion

Tags: wpf, binding, nested

To have less redundant XAML markup i try to get a radiobutton-type selection control to be populated generically, i.e. i use an `ItemsControl` with an enum as `ItemsSource` and create a DataTemplate which shows which item is selected by checking whether the enum value of the item is the same as the current setting.

This alone cannot be done using a simple converter or DataTrigger because two bindings are needed, so i created a generic `MutliValueConverter` to check for equality:

```
<CheckBox.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityComparisonConv}">
        <Binding Path="Key"/>
        <Binding Path="DisplayMode_Current" Source="{x:Static local:App.Settings}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.Visibility>
```

```
public class EqualityComparisonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2) throw new Exception("At least two inputs are needed for comparison");
        bool output = (bool)values.Skip(1).Aggregate(values[0], (x1, x2) => { return x1.Equals(x2); });
        return output;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The obvious problem here is that the converter returns a boolean which i would need to convert to `Visibility` first.

Wrapping the MultiBinding in another binding with just a converter does not work because the properties are not dependency properties (hence cannot have a binding assigned to them). I could think of a few workarounds like storing the bool in some `Tag` property, so i can use that as a new binding source, but i would be more interested in something like this:

```
<CheckBox.Visibility>
    <local:PipeConverter Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConv}">
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityComparisonConv}">
            <Binding Path="Key"/>
            <Binding Path="DisplayMode_Current" Source="{x:Static local:App.Settings}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:PipeConverter>
</CheckBox.Visibility>
```

This class would need to update its output when changes in the original binding occur and it would need to be able to expose its output value to the `Visibility` property but i do not know how to achieve either. One problem one runs into is that there is a need for dependency properties so inheriting from `DependencyObject` would be nice, but inheriting from a Binding class would also make sense because the PipeConverter should bind and needs to be set as the value of another dependency property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

**Option A**: Convert your bool to visibility in your multivalueconverter (its just one line)

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length < 2)
        throw new Exception("At least two inputs are needed for comparison");
    bool output = (bool)values.Skip(1).Aggregate(values[0], (x1, x2) =>
         { return x1.Equals(x2); });
    return output ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**Option B**: Use the existing booltovisibilityconverter programatically

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length < 2)
        throw new Exception("At least two inputs are needed for comparison");
    bool output = (bool)values.Skip(1).Aggregate(values[0], (x1, x2) =>
         { return x1.Equals(x2); });
    System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter booltovisibilityconverter = new System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
    return booltovisibilityconverter.Convert(output, System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"), parameter, culture);
}
```

PS: You may want to cache the booltovisibilityconverter instead of creating it everytime.

**Option C**: Pipe your converters

[Piping Value Converters in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PipingValueConverters_WPF.aspx)

PS: Beaware that this article is quite old.

Comment: A & B is not what i want to do (i want converters to stay generic), i think i'll pick up the idea of C and write my own implementation unless there is a better option...

Comment: @H.B., then i believe, C fits your need. Additionally, its a generic solution to such requirement.

Comment: I went with a pipe-converter, thanks. (I detailed my proceedings it in an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the idea (see [publicgk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524885/nested-binding-and-piped-conversion/5525466#5525466), [option C](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PipingValueConverters_WPF.aspx)) that one can create a converter which contains a collection of converters which internally are used in sequence i wrote a shoddy implementation which fits my needs. i.e. i can use a MultiValueConverter at the beginning and pipe the output into a list of normal converters:

```
[ContentProperty("Converters")]
public class GroupConverter : IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
{
    private IMultiValueConverter _multiValueConverter;
    public IMultiValueConverter MultiValueConverter
    {
        get { return _multiValueConverter; }
        set { _multiValueConverter = value; }
    }

    private List<IValueConverter> _converters = new List<IValueConverter>();
    public List<IValueConverter> Converters
    {
        get { return _converters; }
        set { _converters = value; }
    }

    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GroupConvert(value, Converters);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GroupConvertBack(value, Converters.ToArray().Reverse());
    }

    private static object GroupConvert(object value, IEnumerable<IValueConverter> converters)
    {
        return converters.Aggregate(value, (acc, conv) => { return conv.Convert(acc, typeof(object), null, null); });
    }

    private static object GroupConvertBack(object value, IEnumerable<IValueConverter> converters)
    {
        return converters.Aggregate(value, (acc, conv) => { return conv.ConvertBack(acc, typeof(object), null, null); });
    }
    #endregion

    #region IMultiValueConverter Members
    private InvalidOperationException _multiValueConverterUnsetException =
        new InvalidOperationException("To use the converter as a MultiValueConverter the MultiValueConverter property needs to be set.");

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (MultiValueConverter == null) throw _multiValueConverterUnsetException;
        var firstConvertedValue = MultiValueConverter.Convert(values, targetType, parameter, culture);
        return GroupConvert(firstConvertedValue, Converters);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (MultiValueConverter == null) throw _multiValueConverterUnsetException;
        var tailConverted = GroupConvertBack(value, Converters.ToArray().Reverse());
        return MultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(tailConverted, targetTypes, parameter, culture);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

(*As you can see i pretty much completely disregard the `ConverterParameters`, `TargetTypes` and `CultureInfo` parameters, further the `ConvertBack` methods are untested so i do not advise anyone to actually use this.*)

XAML usage:

```
<vc:GroupConverter MultiValueConverter="{StaticResource EqualityComparisonConv}">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="BoolToVisibilityConv"/>
</vc:GroupConverter>
```