# WPF difficult binding: bind value to IConverter with as input the result from a static method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

I was wondering if it's possible to have the following type of binding, and I couldn't form a search query that gave me definitive answer, or find it anywhere.

Here is the case.

I have a ListBox with 'Items' (a custom class) these items are displayed using an item template. I use a converter to calculate the back ground color. See below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- snip -->
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Name="listBoxMaterialType" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems, ElementName=MySource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now for better abstraction I would like MyConverter to not convert an Item, but only to convert the score of an item. An item does not know it's own score, but the score is calculated by calling MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod(item);  So in code I would like to do a binding like this:   myTextBlock.Background= MyConverter(MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod(item));  is it possible to do this in WPF with data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally it would be the role of the ViewModel to take the your domain object and expose the data required by the view. This can include adding new properties which are aggregates or conversions of model properties (e.g. Supplying a FullName property by concatenating the FirstName and Surname model properties). In your case:

```
public class Item
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    private Item _model;

    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _model.DisplayText; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod(_model);
    }
}
```

Then, using the ViewModel as your DataContext, you can bind your converter directly to the Score property.

Comment: Although this problem does not solve my problem percee, I think it is the best answer because it 'solves' the underlying problem that I tried to solve with XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot of things, e.g. you could add a few properties to your converter which point it towards a method. Those could be for example `TargetType`, `TargetObject` & `MethodName`, then you can - by specifying `MethodName` and either of the other properties - make the converter call the method on the `TargetObject` or statically.

e.g. something like this:

```
//<Property declarations>

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool staticCall = TargetObject == null;
    var types = new Type[] { value.GetType() };
    var args = new object[] { value };
    MethodInfo method;
    if (staticCall)
    {
        method = TargetType.GetMethod(MethodName, types);
    }
    else
    {
        method = TargetObject.GetType().GetMethod(MethodName, types);
    }
    var score = method.Invoke(TargetObject, args);

    //Convert score
}
```

*(As with all sketchy snippets, do not mindlessly copy-paste this, it probably sucks)*

```
<vc:MyConverter x:Key="ScoreConverter"
                TargetType="{x:Type local:MyStaticClass}"
                MethodName="MyStaticMethod"/>
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat option, but feels a bit hacky :).

Comment: It's not hacky at all, the whole binding system relies on reflection like this. Also in [`Interactivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) you can find a [`CallMethodAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction(v=Expression.40).aspx) which is similar but more restrictive as it needs a `TargetObject`.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. I'm still a bit wary about using all that reflection, but indeed all the bindings could not be done without it. I'll give this snippet a try. (ofc not just c/p-ing ;) )

Comment: You might also want to consider using some pipe-converter as this seems to compound two seperate converters, a method-converter and a score-to-brush-converter. I asked a question about how to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524885/nested-binding-and-piped-conversion), option C in the accepted answer is of interest, or see [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524885/nested-binding-and-piped-conversion/5534535#5534535) to the question for a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the converter does its work, by applying the static function you're describing: from an item to a color. Everything goes well.

The problem would arise if you consider that the color may change upon some condition on the score. In which way do you think the binding can be triggered to update the color value (thus calling the converter)?

I guess that it's much more a structural problem instead of a technical one.

EDIT:
Either I don't understand the problem, or the solution is straightforward:

```
    public class MyConverter
        : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(
            object value, 
            Type targetType, 
            object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod(value as MyItem);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
            object value, 
            Type targetType, 
            object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I'd add Mode=OneTime to the binding clause as well.

Cheers

Comment: I only require a one way (once) binding from the score assigned to the item to the background color of the control. The scores do not change, and you can't change to color to have the score change. I currently use your way of applying the static function inside the converter but this tightly ties my converter to a scorer.

Comment: About the edit: that's about the code I wanted to avoid (although the converter first converts the return value of MyStaticMethod) but which I have now for the moment.